# Is it safe to partially open a gas valve?

Tags: gas, valve, stove

I have a stove whose primary burners are all way too hot even at their lowest setting, which means i only have one burner that can actually simmer a liquid or cool more delicate veggies.

Edit: In response to the stove type I have no idea and don't know how to find out. I am on natural gas though, and the oven holds the correct temperature so i assume it's a gas range. Just the cheapest one that money can buy.

Comment: Are you on natural gas or propane and is the stove set for the correct gas?

Comment: That may be as designed.  An extremely low flame could go out with a mild gust of wind.  And then your house would blow up.

Comment: Perhaps there is a gas pressure issue in your lines - probably worth having a gas-certified plumber look at your system if there is not an obvious defect in the stove.

Comment: These are all questions for my slumlord landlord, unfortunately. I am on natural gas, though.

Comment: There are various flame diffusers designed for gas stoves when cooking delicate things. They spread the heat wider, but also waste some, so reduce the heating of your plan. They're not ideal but might help, and they're cheap